# Regex for Names where the middle and last names are optional. (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match space seperated names that do not contain any special character.
The first name is compulsory and the middle and last names are optional. 
Also, the names could have all capital letters, but not all small, and the first character of each of the names(first, middle, last) is a capital letter.

I am using the following regex, but it doesn't seem to work :

"[A-Z]\w+\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?:)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?:)?"

**Edit :** This works like a gem :
 "[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z](\w+)?)?(?:\s[A-Z](\w+)?)?"

Comment: shouldn't it be `[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+?)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?)?` ? Otherwise it expect 2 white spaces when the middle name is missing. EDIT: also I think there is a mistake at ?:), should be ?)

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't seem to work".

Comment: You might want to check this out for quick testing : https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: @ScottHunter I am not getting any matches, however when i remove the optional part, i am able to match the first names.

Comment: @DanieleBernardini Yeah, the syntax was wrong. Thanks ! Now am able to get all but the last names. For names with first and last names, am able ot get first name and two characters from last name. And for names with 3 names am getting the first and the second name but only first two characters of last name. And none of the single names (only first names) are getting matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is

```
^[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+?)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?)?$
```

to match beginning and end of the string if your name comes by itself. Otherwise, if it is embedded in a text, then you want something like

```
\s[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+?)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?)?[\s\.\,\;\:]
```